# PHP подключение к нескольким таблицам базы данных

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysqli

У меня БД с несколькими таблицами. Название таблиц по категориям. БД это рецепты а таблицы : супы, десерты итд.
Как мне подключиться ко всем таблицам?

$sql = "SELECT * FROM day_recipe"; ЧТО ВЫБРАТЬ ЗДЕСЬ ?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM day_recipe` получит все записи из таблицы day_recipe.. вообще вопрос до жути тупой и бессмысленный) вам нужно получить информацию из всех таблиц в ваш скрипт?)

Answer (score 0):

> БД это рецепты а таблицы : супы, десерты итд

Начнем с того что никто так не делает от слова совсем! У вас крайне далекое понимание о работе SQL в целом, и я вам крайне рекомендую прочитать хотя-бы крохотную книжку по SQL - как они работают.

По сути реляционная база данных - подразумевает связь данных, а вы её разрушили. Поэтому данные и не склеиваются.

По поводу как найти таблицу в своей базе - для этого есть техническая БД называется `information_schema` в ней есть таблица `tables`. Там содержится полная информация о всех доступных для вас таблицах.

По поводу как запросить данные из разных таблиц и склеить их - есть `UNION SELECT` - но с ним работать надо обдуманно и аккуратно.

И еще одно очень важное замечание! Перестаньте использовать mysqli - он древний и очень далек от безопасного. Его уже давно обернули в PDO, а над PDO уже есть много вкусных и приятных в работе библиотек! Например тот-же RedBeanPHP имеет все свойства CRUD при этом крайне дружественен к новичкам.

PS: это всего лишь заметки а не полноценный ответ, полноценный ответ вы не сможете получить потому что не до конца понятна суть вопроса, след раз когда задаёте вопрос, пожалуйста обдумайте его внимательнее - мы не Ванги, гадать не умеем.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо, читаю SQL-быстрое-погружение. Я не волшебник а только учусь, а на ошибках учатся. А UNION SELECT мне помог. Буду разбираться дальше.

Comment: @ukrudefr UNION SELECT старайтесь не использовать. Повторюсь - он очень гадкий. По факту он под капотом блокирует таблицы когда производит сбор данных и очень сильно бьёт по базе.

Comment: хорошо, тогда подскажите мне как лучше: я создаю веб страницу рецептов на реакте и php .
База данных у  меня recipes а таблицы с названиями по категориям: soup, dessert ... Все таблицы имеют одинаковые поля: id, name. ingredients, description, image.
Как мне подклюычиться ко всем таблицам и вывести их с помщью реакта? 
Или же связать их по категориям, а вот как вывести на страничку не знаю. Учусь сама по поискам в интернете.

Comment: @ukrudefr Я бы создал просто колонку в таблице `recipes` - `category` и помещал все рецепты в одну таблицу. id, category, name, ingredients, description, image - **где category это и есть "soup", "dessert", ...**

Ты посмотрела что я писал про RedBeansPHP? В бинсе это бы выглядело просто вот так - `echo json_encode(R::getAll('SELECT * FROM recipes' ));`

Comment: Серьёзно хотя-бы попробуй почитать документацию https://redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/quick_tour

Comment: спасибо ещё раз. Я уже сама думала, создать только одну таблицу. Просто это мой первый проект и я ещё никогда не видела реально как выглядят большие базы данных и как с ними работать. 
И за ссылку тоже спасибо, буду изучать. 
Может подкинешь ещё пару ссылок о Reactjs , PHP?

Comment: @ukrudefr По реакту для новичков есть прям очень сочный канал на YT https://www.youtube.com/@mishanep он где-то год назад отснял серию роликов по ракту, где правильно и по полочкам рассказал что да как =) По поводу PHP я бы наверно начинал с https://php.ru/manual/ и наверно всё-же стремился к фреймворкам на подобие Laravel. https://laravel.su/docs/8.x/installation просто знать PHP или уметь пользоваться фреймворком это как-бы большая разница, на чистом PHP уже давно некто не пишет, все рутинные задачи на себя берёт фреймворк, а тебе остаётся только творить чудесные приложения! )

Comment: @ukrudefr Да и если пойдёшь на работу программистом будут именно знания фреймворков спрашивать. И со знанием Laravel твои шансы найти крутую работу увеличиваются вдвое ) Скажем так, работая в команде выйти из статуса новичка можно менее чем за год. В боевых задачах под присмотром опытных программистов учишься в десять раз быстрее.

Comment: спасибо, и ещё один вопрос, лучше  React  PHP или React Node js?

Comment: @ukrdefr вообще не в курсе что такое ReactPHP

Comment: извини, вопрос поставлен по тупому. В большинстве используют frontend React  и backend Node js или frontend React  и backend PHP.  и как лучше ?

Comment: @ukrudefr зависит от задачи, если ты пишешь новостной сайт, интернет магазин или как в твоем случае книгу рецептов, то лучше вообще отказаться от JS и использовать его по минимуму в пользу индексирования поисковиками. А если это B2B, админка или что-то динамичное как онлайн игра, то там без React или Vue делать нечего. В играх вообще PHP заменят на сигналы/сокет и 90% логики пишется на фронте.